# TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'children' of object '#<Object>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, next.js, typeerror

Next js build with docker goes to internal server error on reload in all routes containing getServerSideProps
package.json

- react: "17.0.2"
- next: "^11.1.2"

Everything works fine **locally** and if I **deploy it without docker**.
but with **docker** after I open website. Everything is fine if I navigate with client side router. But as soon as I reload the page it goes to internal server error and does not rebuild the page
[image]

After checking docker logs I found this

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'children' of object '#<Object>'
    at /app/.next/server/chunks/6859.js:792:29
    at /app/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1067:17
    at mapIntoArray (/app/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:964:23)
    at mapIntoArray (/app/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1004:23)
    at Object.mapChildren [as map] (/app/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1066:3)
    at Head.makeStylesheetInert (/app/.next/server/chunks/6859.js:782:36)
    at Head.render (/app/.next/server/chunks/6859.js:839:23)
    at processChild (/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3450:18)
    at resolve (/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3270:5)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3753:22)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3690:29)
    at Object.renderToStaticMarkup (/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:4314:27)
    at Object.renderToHTML (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:711:41)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async doRender (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:1149:38)
```

Answer (score 0):

That was so weird. I found the problem in my `Dockerfile.prod`. just changed my `ENV NODE_ENV prod` to  `ENV NODE_ENV production`.
I did change that after I noticed that `NODE_ENV` have only 3 valid options

- production
- development
- test